# Magento back end -Can't log into admin after M2epro upgrade

Tags: php, magento

We have not installed m2epro through magento connect, hence we couldn't upgrade M2epro. M2epro support team adviced to remove following file and install using Magento connect.

'app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro',
'app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/M2ePro.xml',
'app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/M2ePro',
'app/etc/modules/Ess_M2ePro.xml',
'js/M2ePro',
'skin/adminhtml/default/default/M2ePro',
'skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/M2ePro'

After clearing cache we try to install M2epro using Magento connect, we were getting 'couldn't connect to host' error.

Here is the extension link we used;
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/m2epro_ebay_magento
After that we give permission and installed M2epro. Cleared all cache manually and restored permission. Now we can't log into admin side. We are getting following error.

"Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in '/var/www/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 96"

Please let us know how we can fix this.

Comment: When I reinstalled , i am getting following error;

Exception during cache and session cleaning: Error in file: "/var/www/site/public_html/app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/sql/M2ePro_setup/mysql4-upgrade-6.0.3-6.0.4.php" - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_english_measurement_system' in 'm2epro_ebay_marketplace' 

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, disable M2EPro (in `app/etc/modules`). That should narrow down the problem a fair way for you. If the site comes back up, I'd recommend removing M2EPro entirely and reinstalling it.

The line where the error is occurring is setting the active menu item, and it's saying there is no menu block, which is a little strange. My guess is that maybe a file that shouldn't have been deleted has been deleted. Can you restore from a backup?